# Keras and VGG training: why do I "lose" training and validation examples following model.predict_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am training VGG on some of my own images. 
I have the following code:

```
img_width, img_height = 512, 512
top_model_weights_path = 'UIP-versus-inconsistent.h5'
train_dir = 'MasterHRCT/Limited-Cuts-UIP-Inconsistent/train'
validation_dir = 'MasterHRCT/Limited-Cuts-UIP-Inconsistent/validation'
nb_train_samples = 1500
nb_validation_samples = 500
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

def save_bottleneck_features():

        datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

        model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

        generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_dir, 
            target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
            shuffle=False, 
            class_mode=None,
            batch_size=batch_size
        )  

        bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator=generator, steps=nb_train_samples // batch_size)

        np.save(file="UIP-versus-inconsistent_train.npy", arr=bottleneck_features_train)

        generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_dir, 
            target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
            shuffle=False,
            class_mode=None,  
            batch_size=batch_size,    
        )

        bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

        np.save(file="UIP-versus-inconsistent_validate.npy", arr=bottleneck_features_validation)

                generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    validation_dir, 
                    target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
                    shuffle=False,
                    class_mode=None,  
                    batch_size=batch_size,    
                )

                bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

                np.save(file="UIP-versus-inconsistent_validate.npy", arr=bottleneck_features_validation)
```

Following execution of this I get, as expected based on my directory

```
 Found 1500 images belonging to 2 classes.
 Found 500 images belonging to 2 classes
```

Then I run

```
 train_data = np.load(file="UIP-versus-inconsistent_train.npy")
 train_labels = np.array([0] * 750 + [1] * 750)
 validation_data = np.load(file="UIP-versus-inconsistent_validate.npy")
 validation_labels = np.array([0] * 250 + [1] * 250)
```

And then inspect the data

```
 print("Train data shape", train_data.shape)
 print("Train_labels shape", train_labels.shape)
 print("Validation_data shape", validation_labels.shape)
 print("Validation_labels", validation_labels.shape)
```

And I get

```
Train data shape (1488, 16, 16, 512)
Train_labels shape (1488,)
Validation_data shape (496,)
Validation_labels (496,)
```

And this is variable - instead of having 1500 training data examples and 500 validation examples it's like I "lose" some. Sometimes when I run 
     save_bottleneck_features():
The numbers come back right, other times they don't. It happens a lot when the process takes a long time. Is there a reproducible explanation for this? Corrupted image perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
1488 = (1500 // batch_size) * batch_size
496 = (500 // batch_size) * batch_size
```

Your loss comes from integer division inaccuracy.

Comment: Hmm...too easy :(